# What plant will grow to about 3' in the shade from a pepper tree and oleanders?

Tags: trees, plant-recommendations, shade

Is there a low light plant, that will grow under a pepper tree, and between two oleanders,
that grows about 3-5 feet tall, in southern California?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend Taxus baccata 'repandens', English Spreading Yew.  One of the few conifers that grows in shade! Does well in sun but in S. California I think you'd want this in the part-shade to shade and you want this to grow under your pepper tree. Don't prune this...it gets up to 3' with graceful, arching branches providing an excellent 'foundation' plant...or skeleton plant. These are plants that 'pull' your landscape together forming the 'bones' of your landscape.

Let me know if this isn't a good plant for your area. I've little experience with plants down there..

Comment: It grows in CA and the photos of it look good.
I had given up hope for an answer.
Cant help saying thanks, Stormy